# Make a dataframe consisting of multiple lists as rows, Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to make a dataframe consisting of the lists below as rows. Does someone know how to do this quickly without manually making a dict first? Thank you! The elements in the list are floats.

```
p000 = [p000_1,p000_2,p000_3,p000_4,p000_5,p000_6,p000_7,p000_8,p000_9,p000_10]
p100 = [p100_1, p100_2, p100_3, p100_4, p100_5, p100_6, p100_7, p100_8, p100_9, p100_10]
p200 = [p200_1, p200_2, p200_3, p200_4, p200_5, p200_6, p200_7, p200_8, p200_9, p200_10]
p300 = [p300_1, p300_2, p300_3, p300_4, p300_5, p300_6, p300_7, p300_8, p300_9, p300_10]
p400 = [p400_1, p400_2, p400_3, p400_4, p400_5, p400_6, p400_7, p400_8, p400_9, p400_10]
p500 = [p500_1, p500_2, p500_3, p500_4, p500_5, p500_6, p500_7, p500_8, p500_9, p500_10]
p600 = [p600_1, p600_2, p600_3, p600_4, p600_5, p600_6, p600_7, p600_8, p600_9, p600_10]
p700 = [p700_1, p700_2, p700_3, p700_4, p700_5, p700_6, p700_7, p700_8, p700_9, p700_10]
p800 = [p800_1, p800_2, p800_3, p800_4, p800_5, p800_6, p800_7, p800_8, p800_9, p800_10]
p900 = [p900_1, p900_2, p900_3, p900_4, p900_5, p900_6, p900_7, p900_8, p900_9, p900_10]
p1000 =  [p1000_1, p1000_2, p1000_3, p1000_4, p1000_5, p1000_6, p1000_7, p1000_8, p1000_9, p1000_10]
```

Comment: Are "p000_1" all strings? If so, please edit your code to include the quotes.

Comment: @not_speshal they are all floats, just added it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a `dict`. You can use [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([p000,p100,p200,p300,p400,p500,p600,p700,p800,p900,p1000])
```

Comment: Thank you! Dou you maybe also know if I can keep the p000,p100,p200 etc as row names or as the first column?

Comment: If you mean the strings, you can do `df.index = ["p000", "p100"...]`. If you mean the float values, you can do `df = df.set_index(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

p100 = [1,2,3,4]
p200 = [1,2,3,4]
p300 = [1,2,3,4]
p400 = [1,2,3,4]
p500 = [1,2,3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame([globals()[f'p{i}'] for i in range(100, 600, 100)], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df
```

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
2   1   2   3   4
3   1   2   3   4
4   1   2   3   4
```